# Calling function defined in another header file in a class in C++

Tags: c++, include, header-files

I am trying to use a shiftreg.h with a shiftreg.cpp (which I previously used successfully in my main file) in a class and call upon one of his functions. Sadly is does not compile and gives the error: **'shiftWrite' was not declared in this scope**. I think I included every header file in every other and they should find each other. What is going wrong?

This is shiftreg.h:

```
#ifndef shiftreg_h
#define shiftreg_h

void shiftWrite(uint8_t data);

#endif
```

And this shiftreg.cpp:

```
#include "ShiftReg.h"

void shiftWrite(uint8_t data) {
    do something;}
```

The function shiftWrite, I want to use in a function of the class SegmentDisplay as below, with the SegmentDisplay.h

```
#ifndef SegmentDisplay_h
#define SegmentDisplay_h

#include <ShiftReg/shiftReg.h>

class SegmentDisplay{
public:
    void pickNumber(int x);
};

#endif
```

And the SegmentDispplay.cpp:

```
#include "SegmentDisplay.h"

void SegmentDisplay::pickNumber(int x){
    shiftWrite(ONE);}
```

It all starts in the Arduino software with:

```
  #include "SegShift.h"

  SegmentDisplay dsp();

  int main(void){
      while(1){
          dsp.pickNumber(j);}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be including two different files:

In ShiftReg.cpp you do: `#include "ShiftReg.h"`

In SegmentDisplay.h you do `#include <ShiftReg/shiftReg.h>`

(Incidentally, I'd just include shiftreg.h in your SegmentDisplay.cpp.)

Comment: ShiftReg.h is in a different folder then SegmentDisplay.h. thats why I do <ShiftReg/ShiftReg.h>. If I don't, it does not even find the library.

Comment: I added #include <ShiftReg/ShiftReg.h> to the SegmentDisplay.cpp, but it gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

I have added the ShiftReg.h and ShiftReg.cpp files to the folder of the SegmentDisplay files and it compiles! I'm glad I solved the problem with the help of your answers also.

However, I'm wondering why I can not use the files when they are in a different folder. Any ideas?

Comment: Your problem was in ShiftReg.cpp you were not including the same file. That one should have been `#include <ShiftReg/ShiftReg.h>` also.

Comment: When I'm adding #include <ShiftReg/ShiftReg.h> to ShiftReg.cpp, it also doesn't work. There is only one file on the computer that is called ShiftReg.h and that is in the folder ShiftReg.

Answer (score -1):

In SegmentDisplay.h you must include shiftreg.cpp not shiftreg.h

Otherwise the code does not see that function diclared

Comment: changing #include <shiftReg/shiftReg.h> to #include <shiftReg/shiftReg.cpp> in SegmentDisplay.h gives the same error

Comment: There's no reason to `#include` a `.cpp` file in this case, or the majority of cases.